# What's the difference between CALayer -drawInContext: and -renderInContext:?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

What's the difference between CALayer -drawInContext: and -renderInContext: ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When providing custom Quartz-drawn content to display within a CALayer, you can override `-drawInContext:` and do your custom drawing there.  This is similar to `-drawRect:` for a UIView or NSView.  Alternatively, you can set another class to be the delegate of the CALayer and implement `-drawLayer:inContext:` to provide custom content to a standard CALayer.

You don't override `-renderInContext:`, but instead you can call this on a layer to render it and all of its sublayers into a particular Core Graphics context.  Note that this won't render certain types of layers (like those with OpenGL content).  It also doesn't behave the way you'd expect when rendering into a PDF context, where the layers will come out as bitmapped rectangles instead of pure vector elements.  To work around this, you might want to check out the [Core Plot framework's CPTLayer implementation](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/master/framework/Source/CPTLayer.m), where we bypass the normal rendering process in order to preserve the vectors in a PDF generated from our CALayer subclass.